# ImportError: cannot import name QtGui

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt

I installed Qt5.3(32 bit) installer on my linux 32 bit computer.

- Then i installed last version of sip - sip4.16.4
- Then i installed last version of pyqt - PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11.3.tar.gz    from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download
- In my computer python2.7 and python3.2 versions are installed. When i try to install with python2.7, i took some errors. Then i tried to install it with pthon3.2. No errors happened, and i installed it correctly using python3.2
- I installed both py2.7-dev and py3.2-dev package.
- gdb,gcc,g++,python2.7,python3.2,build-essential all is installed in my computer.
- I installed Qt Designer from the Software Center.
- Then i put a simple button following the instructions of the tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLqrzLIIW2E
- Then, i save the example.ui
- Then, I give the following command in terminal: pyuic4 example.ui > example.py  . It converted the .ui file to .py file. Then i make the necessary modifications told in the youtube tutorial i told above.

**- When i run the final version of the python file with python3.2, it gives the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "outFile_ui.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: cannot import name QtGui
```

**- Why i am taking this error? I think the problem is at nonmatching version,or installation etc. But i installed again and again. Nothing changed unfortunately. I searched all about the problem on the web. Similar problems exist,however none of them worked for me.**

- If you want to see the python file which i run on the terminal, it is :

  ```
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

  import sys

  try:
      _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
  except AttributeError:
      def _fromUtf8(s):
          return s

  try:
      _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
      def _translate(context, text, disambig):
          return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
  except AttributeError:
      def _translate(context, text, disambig):
          return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)



  class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
      def __init__(self):
          QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
          self.setupUi(self)
      def setupUi(self, Form):
          Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
          Form.resize(400, 300)
          self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Form)
          self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
          self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
          self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
          self.printHam_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
          self.printHam_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("printHam_btn"))
          self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.printHam_btn)
          self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

          self.retranslateUi(Form)
          QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

      def retranslateUi(self, Form):
          Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Super Ham", None))
          self.printHam_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Print HAm", None))
          self.printHam_btn.clicked.connect(self.printHam)

      def printHam(self):
          print ("Ham!")


      if __name__ == '__main__':
          app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
          ex = Ui_Form()
          ex.show()
          sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```

Comment: seems you may shorten your code down to the import statement? Did you try to import QtCore and QtGui in two separate lines?

Comment: Why didn't you just install the binary packages that are provided by your distro (which is ubuntu, I assume)? You've probably installed PyQt to the wrong location, and are now trying to run your script using the wrong Python.

Comment: @ekhumoro , I agree with you.I think the problem is related to the topic you mentioned. But i couldn't solve it. What do you want to mean by saying "Why didn't you just install the binary packages that are provided by your distro" ?? Do you talking about software center or etc.? I didn't understand

Comment: @oiyio. I mean the [pre-compiled packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pyqt&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) that are provided by ubuntu: i.e. the things that you install via [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

Comment: @ekhumoro. I didn't do that since these packages are too much old versions.

Answer (score 1):

After converting .ui to .py code, it is required to add a main function. After main function is added properly, it runs perfectly.